# Alias 2 columns to the same name

Tags: mysql, join, alias

I am wondering if it is possible to alias 2 columns from 2 separate tables to the same name.

For example i want to join an email table with a user table and admin table and let the respective 'name' columns be combined in the same column.

```
Email Table: Email ID | Email Address

User Table: Username| Email ID

Admin Table: Username| Email ID

Result:

Username | Email Address
```

Comment: So you want these columns to be separate, but to have the same name, or did you want them fully merged as well?

Comment: @user1161318 Fully merged, it seems like UNION is the magic keyword that i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to get:

```
SELECT a.Username, a.Email_ID, b.Email_Address
FROM
    (SELECT Username, Email_ID FROM User
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Username, Email_ID FROM Admin) a
INNER JOIN Email b ON b.Email_ID = a.Email_ID
```

This will stack the `User` and `Admin` tables and then `JOIN` the `Email` table.

Note that if there are duplicates and you want to remove them you should use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your tables have the following columns

```
Email: EmailId, EmailAddress
User:  UserName, EmailId
Admin: UserName, EmailId
```

Then The following union should get them into one list. Note I'm using a LEFT JOIN to allow for the cases where EmailId in the User or Admin tables is invalid

```
SELECT  u.UserName, e.EmailAddress
FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN Email e ON e.Id = u.EmailId

UNION

SELECT  a.UserName, e.EmailAddress
FROM Admin u
LEFT JOIN Email e ON e.Id = a.EmailId
```

Comment: The difference between mine and @njk's answer is that I do the joins first and union the result, while he unions the User and Admin tables first and then joins. It's valid either way, but I suspect his might be more optimal

Comment: Technically, you're performing two `JOIN`s which depending on the records, may take longer.

Comment: This was a very simplified example, so I'll be reading up on UNION so i can make an efficient query

Comment: @njk Yes - I agree but it's only one statement overall so possibly the optimiser may be kind. But I think your approach is sounder.